# Querying yahoo finance for data

Tags: java, stocks

I am querying yahoo finance to get the price of 2000 stocks. When i put all the two thousand stocks togetther in the symbol it returns http 414 error.How can i get past this.

Comment: yeah i heard that the threshold is 1500 per minute...maybe you can try reducing your request

Answer (score 4):

HTTP error 414 means that the URL you are sending the server is too long. In essence you will need to formulate a plan for breaking your request up into more manageable chunks for Yahoo!. I'm unsure of what the maximum length is, but maybe consider editing your code to go through stock by stock and query.

Comment: If i break it into smaller chunks and query repeatedly some of the stocks which i query go missing. That is they are skipped.